# scheme and set!

Tags: variables, lisp, scheme

How can I change the value of a variable via a function that consumes lambda parameter?
Ie:

```
;;definitions
(define test "fails")
(define (experiment input) (set! input "works"))

;;interactions
> test
"fails"
> (experiment test)
> test
"fails"
```

This seems to fail..

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot -- Scheme passes all values "by value", so in the above the `experiment` function simply modifies its own input argument.  To get something like this working, you can use a box, which is an explicitly mutable value container:

```
(define test (box "fails"))
(define (experiment input) (set-box! input "works"))
(unbox test)
(experiment test)
(unbox test)
```

If you *really* want to change the value of a variable, you can use a macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (experiment input) (set! input "works"))
```

This creates `experiment` as a macro, which means that every `(experiment foo)` form is getting rewritten into `(set! foo "works")`.  This can have subtle consequences, so it's not a good idea to use this unless you know what you're doing.  (For example, `(experiment 2)` will fail in an "interesting" way.)  Writing macros in Scheme is easy, but writing *good* macros is still more difficult than writing a new function definition.

[Note that I'm assuming you're using PLT Scheme in this answer.  But both parts can be translated into "standard" Scheme if needed -- for example, use a mutable `cons` cell for the first, and use `define-syntax` with `syntax-rules` for the second.]

Comment: This can also be done with parameters: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-39/srfi-39.html

Comment: Yes, parameters are another mutable kind of a container (and PLT has several more of them, like `thread-cell`).  But the semantics of those can be subtly different than a plain global.  For example, a parameter has a unique value for each thread (more exactly, a unique value for each continuation).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would make more sense if you consider the same code in Python:

```
test = "fails"
def experiment(input):
  input = "works"

>>> test
'fails'
>>> experiment(test)
>>> test
'fails'
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?